# How to display data in new TAB for CSV (C#)

Tags: c#, csv, export-to-csv

Language: C#

I want to output my data in a csv file. The data retrieval and display is working already but is it possible to display data per group in a separate TAB when user opens the CSV?

Right now, I am using a 'comma' as a separator and my data looks like this when I open the CSV:

[image]

What I wanted to accomplish is for the second group of data under "Name" and Gender" to be output in a separate tab for example:

[image]

So in the end, first tab is for the NAME and AGE. Second tab is for the NAME and GENDER. Is this feasible to achieve? Thank you.

Comment: I think "Tab" is excel concept...

Comment: Yes, you save it as *.csv but then you can open using excel.

Comment: What I am trying to say is that you can create CSV files and open it with Excel, and in *Excel* you can add *Tab*, but I think the CSV format itself doesn't have concept of Tab. Thus it *maybe* impossible to do what you want *if* the format is pure CSV and not doing it with Excel (which open CSV file as one of its worksheet, but you *still* use *Excel* and therefore can create tab in *Excel* - not due to the CSV file itself you can create tab. The concept may not exist).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot create multiple "sheets" within a pure CSV file. Tabs are an Excel-only concept and are not part of most raw file formats.

I would recommend using Office interop or a third-party library to generate native excel documents,